# Copy localhost MySQL database to remote server with Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

Simple question here: I have a Java class that processes several thousand objects, then writes data to a remote MySQL database (two tables per object, one is a simple INSERT the other is INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE). All write operations are done within a single MySQL connection, but it still takes around 1 hour to complete writing, depending on the network connection. Is there a way to simply write all that data to a localhost database first and then migrate the entire database to a remote server in one go using Java? Current size of DB is < 50 MB but it will grow with time.

Comment: Yes, there's such a thing as 'replication' but Java doesn't really enter into it. You'd use MySql tools to do this

Comment: Are you batch processing the objects?  If you, you can disable indices in the target db, do the inserts, then enable the indices.  This may help.  no guarantee.

Comment: @DwB That would leave the upserts having duplicate records would it not?

Comment: I'm not sure about the upsert functionality.  I believe an upsert should attempt to update first, then insert.  That should not depend on an index.

Comment: Yes, you're right